# IDS Evasion Techniques and tools over several protocols

Tags: network-security

I need some IDS evasion attacks to test an IDS product.All I can find is an old paper titled "Insertion, Evasion and Denial Of Service: Eluding NIDS" by Thomas.H.Ptacek and Tim Newsham.
It is kind of too old,and there must be some new ways through those years.Also there maybe some other tools like fragroute.I need to find them.

So give me some clue where to find it. 
Thanks.

And here is what is evasion attack from the paper I mentioned:
An end-system can accept a packet that an IDS rejects. An IDS that mistakenly rejects such a packet misses its contents entirely. This condition can also be exploited, this time by slipping crucial information past the IDS in packets that the IDS is too strict about processing. These packets are `evading'' the scrutiny of the IDS. We call these`evasion'' attacks.

Answer (score 0):

The paper by Ptacek is one of the most commonly cited source in this problem space. A generalization of this problem concerns **traffic normalization**. [Handley and Paxson](http://www.icir.org/vern/papers/norm-usenix-sec-01.pdf) discuss this topic in detail and developed an inline application that sits at the network edge to remove potential traffic ambiguities that may lead to evasion opportunities.

As such, if you deploy such a traffic normalizer, evaluating an IDS with respect to evasion due to traffic ambiguities becomes less of a concern.

By the way, the [Bro NIDS](http://www.bro-ids.org) has been built with resistance against evasion from the beginning. For details, please refer to the [original paper](http://www.icir.org/vern/papers/bro-CN99.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

I have got the list but you have to search one by one separately.

- Evasion Attack
- Insertion Attack
- DoS attack
- Obfuscation
- False positive generation
- Session Splicing
- Unicode Evasion Technique
- Fragmentation Attack
- Overlapping Fragments
- TTL attacks
- Invalid RST Packets
- Urgency Flag
- Polymorphic Shellcode
- ASCII Shellcode
- Application Layer Attack
- DeSynchronization- Pre-Connection SYN
- DeSynchronization- Post-Connection SYN
- Encryption and Flooding